# Server with multiple clients and message forwarding

Tags: c++, server, client

I have a Server running and listening on a port for incomming connections. When a Client establishes a connection it is put in a ThreadPool and set on run.

The Clients should be able to send messages between them, not only to the server, which basically forwards the received messages to another client.

I am using C++ and Qt, so when I get a new Client I put it in a `QThreadPool`:

```
    Client c = new Client();
    pool->start(c);
```

But I cannot search for specific Clients in this pool therefore I thought of storing the Clients in an List as well which can be searched.

The clients have a data structure with outgoing and incoming messages which can then be handled by iterating through the list with the clients by a server thread.

Is this a good approach or is there a better way to solve this? Is the pool even necessary any more if I store them in the List too?

Comment: The pool avoid allocation and thus minimize risks. Why you cannot read for other clients in the pool?

In the other hands, be sure to use the correct inter-threading/process synchronization to avoid race/dead-lock/etc..

Comment: I am using QThreadPool and I did not find a way to search for a specific thread there, I am wrong about that? Would it be better to use a callback function passed to the Client for the incomming messages?

Comment: Well, that is THE big problem of QT, all classes miss something and it is sometimes hard to extend them. I do not know a lot about the problem you are trying to solve and its requirements, but in my opinion, the first question should be to minimize the synchronization time: Make a per to per communication between clients, concentrate the communication through the server, or even to mix different solutions for different types of data. It depends also a lot about the expected client load: huge number of clients with short time/ small amount with long alive time.

Comment: Can you recomment another library that provides a specific thread selection? Boost maybe?

Comment: I am not saying QT is wrong, you could look at the source code and implement your own pool which allow what you need. Boost is of course another solution, but I do know about any thread pool (even if thread and pool exist independently). You could also look at C++ STL